# How to generate random operator after each random operand using php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Here is my code for random operand generator:

```
$randomOperands = array();

// do a loop over $i n times
for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i ++) {
    // assign random operand to array slot
    $randomOperands[] = rand(0, 9);
}
// print array values:
foreach($randomOperands as $key=>$value1){
    echo  $value1 "<br />"; 
}
```

But how can I generate random operator just after each random operand?

This is my form through which user will give his input and the n no.of questions having random sequence containing  n(no.of operands user wants, he can give input for this within the range of 1 to 10 ) operands and n-1 operators and answer of the sequence  will be generated after clicking on generate button.

```
   <form action="" method="POST">
   Select no.of questions:<input type="number" name="que" value="que">
   <br>
   <br>
   Select no. of series: <select name="select">
    <option value="0"> 2 </option>
    <option value="1"> 3 </option>
    <option value="2"> 4 </option>
    <option value="3"> 5 </option>
    <option value="4"> 6 </option>
    <option value="5"> 7 </option>
    <option value="6"> 8 </option>
    <option value="7"> 9 </option>
    <option value="8"> 10 </option>
   </select>

     <br><br>
     Select number type(in digits) :
     <select name="select_box">
    <option value="0">1</option>
    <option value="1"> 2 </option>
    <option value="2"> 3 </option>
    <br><br>
  </select>
  <br /><br />
   Select operations:<br />
   <input type="checkbox" id="add" name="operation" value="addition"  
   onclick="doOperation()"><label>Addition</label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="sub" name="operation" value="subtract"  
    onclick="doOperation()"><label>Subtraction</label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="mult" name="operation" value="multiply"  
   onclick="doOperation()"><label>Multiplication</label>
   <input type="checkbox" id="div" name="operation" value="divide"  
    onclick="doOperation()"><label>Division</label>
    <br><br>

     <br><br>
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Generate"><br>
    <br>
   </form>
```

here in the form  1st field is no.of questions i.e how many questions user wants to get having random sequence.
2nd field is no. of series i.e how many operands user wants in that sequence (if he gave input for 6 or any number between 1 to 10 then the sequence of 6 operands and 5 operators and their ans. will be generated at the end after filling all fields). 
3rd field is no. of digits i.e for how many digits user wnat to generate a sequence, I have given choces only upto 3 digits.
at last, which operations user want to perform for sequence

I know its very tricky task but interseting too.
how can I do it?

Comment: Do you just want to print, or do you also want to calculate? If you want to calculate, what operator precedence do you want? Scientific or immediate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would generate a string of integers and operands.

Note how extra checks are needed to avoid division by zero.

Also, as asked above, do you actually want to evaluate the results in code?

```
 <?php

$potentialOperands = array('+', '-', '*', '/');  //Keep division as the last operand here
$previousInt = null;        //Track the previous operand, else we'll get division by zero

$randomIntegers = array();
$randomOperands = array();

 // do a loop over $i n times
 for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i ++) {
    // assign random operand to array slot
    $nextInt = rand(0, 9);
    $randomIntegers[] = $nextInt;
    if($i < 10){    //No operand after last integer
        if($previousInt === 0){
            //Make sure to avoid a potenial division-by-zero
            $randomOperands[] = $potentialOperands[rand(0, 2)];
        }
        else{
            $randomOperands[] = $potentialOperands[rand(0, 3)];
        }
    }
    $previousInt = $nextInt;
 }

 // print array values:
   $exp = '';
   foreach($randomIntegers as $key=>$value1)
   {
       $exp .=  $value1 . " "; 
       if(isset($randomOperands[$key])){
           $exp .=  $randomOperands[$key] ." "; 
       }
   }

   $res = eval("return ($exp);");

   //Generates answer rounded to 3 decimal places
   //The answer uses standard PHP operator precedence
   printf("%s = %.3f", $exp, $res);
?>
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the reply and yes I  want to generate the result  too in the output along with the expression , how can I generate that  whole expression?

Comment: Be aware that there are several open questions here, such as operator precedence; and when and where to round of division results.

Comment: Thanks a lot its working ..!  Actually , I shoulld have specified it early that the sequence will be randomly generated  so operator precednce ,  actually doesn't matter  here .and the output will be depend on  input given by the user through a form that I have created.

Comment: hey ben , your answer is really helpful, thanks a lot for that . bu I nedd another help, I have updated the question  can you please go through it and give me some suggestion? That would be great.